# Inherited class member with the same name as child constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, gcc, compiler-errors, class-members

Consider this example:

```cpp
    class Label{
    public:
        std::string Text;    
    };

    class Text:
        public Label
    {
    public:
        Text(std::string text) {}
    };

    int main()
    {
        Text text("");
        text.Text; //<---- GCC CE: Invalid use of 'class Text'
        return 0;
    }
```

```cpp
    class Text:
        public Label
    {
    public:
        Text(std::string text) {}
        using Label::Text; // doesn't help either
    };
```

How could one access inherited class member if it has the same name as child class?

```cpp
    class Text:
        public Label
    {
    public:
        Text(std::string text):
            Text::Text(Label::Text){}
        std::string &Text;
    };
```

Could something like this work? (I know that code above does not.)

Comment: There's no *nice* way of accessing the variable. One possible workaround is to use "getters" and "setters" for such variables.

Comment: As an aside: have you noticed how overused the name `Text` is in that code sample? Instead of hacking around the issue you're having, perhaps it would benefit the clarity if you pick different names for the things you are dealing with.

Comment: I'm implementing wrappers and trying to mimic architecture design of existing elements, with same names of course. So if in existing terms element of type "Text" is child of "Label" and "Label" has "Text" property in it - nothing I can do there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a workaroud (which is quit confusing); you can access data member of base class via the base class name. e.g.

```
text.Label::Text;
```

Comment: Thx. That's some odd syntax for sure. Could you check my update in question please?

Comment: @AlexanderG. I checked it, it seems impossible. Before using it, you can't have data member with same name of the class. https://wandbox.org/permlink/dMdTuCVHYNPRkywx

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact that the right answer is (posted by @songyuanyao)

```cpp
text.Label::Text;
```

I have figured out how to avoid this kinda odd syntax.

Simple "hack" with old C-style typedef will do the trick:

```cpp
    typedef class Text_:
        public Label
    {
    public:
        Text_(std::string text){}
    }Text;
```

And now suddenly code example compiles. *Woah*...*C++ magic*...

Comment: No need to use C syntax:`class Text_ : public Label {/*..*/}; using Text = Text_;`, you indeed solve issue using different names and alias has indeed same name that parameter, but not in same scope.

Comment: Actually there is no difference like...at all. Except that 'using' will not work for C++98 and C++03.

Comment: Okay. I should raise a *sarcasm* sign or something like that. =)